# Как установить задержку выполнения выбраного когда php

Tags: php

У меня есть функция:

```
function reSizeImg($file, $width, $height)
{ 
    $fileImg = imagecreatefromwebp('images/users/' . $file);
    $imgOut = $file;
    $img = imagescale($fileImg, $width, $height);
    imagewebp($img, $imgOut);
    echo $imgOut;
    sleep(3);
    unlink($imgOut);
}
```

она создает изображение с указаными размерами ширины и высоты. Я вставляю её в scr:

```
<img src="<?php reSizeImg('test.webp', 100, 100) ?>">
```

после чего, я хочу удалить этот файл, что бы он не занимал место на хостинге, но после удаления, оно не показывает картинку(потому, что она удаляеться быстрее чём выводиться). Я пытался использовать `sleep()`, но все бесполезно

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/151795/. В адрес изображения передаёте адрес скрипта. После вывода содержимого файла, его можно удалить (после `readfile($file);` и до `exit;` если брать первый пример)

Comment: Вы можете создать изображение и вставить его как [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html) в отдаваемый HTML.

Comment: вы эту картинку одноразово показываете? ресурсы ЦП будут подороже чем ресурсы диска. Храните картинки пока они требуются. Раз в неделю вон грохайте все что есть, да и все. Каждый раз генерить картинку налету - затратно будет.